# Starting and stopping listeners in Mojo framework (WebOS)

Tags: prototype, webos, palm-pre, mojo, palm-pre2

I am starting WebOS dev and I have a doubt on where should I start and stop my listeners
?
I am reading [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596155255) book but I couldn't find a clear explanation about this. In the sample the author set the listeners in the setup function but I wonder why? isn't a better idea to set them in activate function and stop them in deactivate function as suggested by the template's comments?

In case I am wrong what kind of [events](http://www.weboshelp.net/webos-mojo-development-resources/api-reference#catid53) should and shouldn't put in setup and activate functions?

When exactly setup, activate, deactivate, cleanup functions are called?

```
StoryViewAssistant.prototype.setup = function() {
    //HERE, OK?
    this.nextStoryHandler = this.nextStory.bindAsEventListener(this); 
    this.previousStoryHandler = this.previousStory.bindAsEventListener(this); 
    this.controller.listen("nextStory", Mojo.Event.tap, this.nextStoryHandler); 
    this.controller.listen("previousStory", Mojo.Event.tap,this.previousStoryHandler);
    /* add event handlers to listen to events from widgets */

};

StoryViewAssistant.prototype.activate = function(event) {
    //HERE? 
    /* put in event handlers here that should only be in effect when this scene is active. For example, key handlers that are observing the document */
};

StoryViewAssistant.prototype.deactivate = function(event) {
    //HERE? 
    /* remove any event handlers you added in activate and do any other cleanup that should happen before this scene is popped or another scene is pushed on top */
};

StoryViewAssistant.prototype.cleanup = function(event) {
    //HERE, OK?
    this.controller.stopListening("nextStore", Mojo.Event.tap, this.nextStoryHandler);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scene assistant's **setup** is called when the scene is created, **cleanup** is called when it's popped off the stack.  In **setup**, the actual HTML content of the controls isn't available, as the template for the scene hasn't been processed yet.  A **ready** method is called if available after that template processing is done, and this is a good spot to do any other HTML DOM changes.  **activate** is called just before the scene becomes active, while **deativate** is called when either the scene is being popped or another scene is being pushed on top of this one.  **activate**/**deactivate** are also called when the app is minimized to a card or brought back to full screen.

It's generally best to start and stop event listeners on activate/deactivate -- that keeps their alive time to a minimum, and fewer active listeners makes a more responsive system.